# Проверка файла file_get_contents

Tags: php

Есть страшный код:

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://домен/domain.txt');
echo "Актуальный домен";
$from = 7;
$to = 7;
$num = $to - $from; // 
$b = substr($homepage, $from);
echo $b;

В файле содержание что-то вроде domain:mydomain.ru
Как можно понять уже - обрезание и сохранение в переменную.
Каким образом можно остановить скрипт ( полностью ).
Дело в том, что данный файл иногда возвращает или не верную конструкцию или пустой файл.
В переменную $b записывается пустота и далее это чревато ошибками с базой данных, куда эта $b записывается.
СпасибО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы в лоб: вызвать функцию die (или exit, они равнозначны). Эта функция немедленно остановит выполнение скрипта и выведет сообщение, принятое в качестве первого аргумента:

```
if (strlen($homepage) === 0) {
    die('К сожалению, $homepage оказался пустой строкой');
}
```

"Правильное" решение проблемы - это построить приложение, которое может реализовать подобный функционал, выносит весь сопровождающий код глубоко "под капот" и оставляет только самое необходимое непосредственно в коде, реализующем логику. Например, примерно так бы это выглядело на Yii:

```
public function actionCheckDomain()
{
    $url = Yii::app()->request->getPost('url', false);
    $homepage = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!is_string($homepage) || strlen($homepage) < 5) {
        throw new CHttpException(502, 'Invalid domain data received');
    }
    $homepage = substr($homepage, 7);
    // дальнейшая обработка
}
```

А если бы получение домена было бы сложной операцией, мы и ее могли бы вынести "за скобки":

```
public function actionCheckDomain()
{
    $url = Yii::app()->request->getPost('url', false);
    if (!$url || ($homepage = $this->_getDomainData($url)) !== false) {
        throw new CHttpException(502, 'Invalid domain data received');
    }
    // дальнейшая обработка
}
protected function _getDomainData($url)
{
    $homepage = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!is_string($homepage) || strlen($homepage) < 5) {
        return false;
    }
    return substr($homepage, 7);
}
```

выглядит запутанно, но должно быть видно, что
а) окончание приложения решается через простой if-else, можно даже сделать это без исключений
б) можно легко оборвать выполнение исключением, которое автоматом выведет оформленную ошибку
в) как только функционал разрастается, он легко делится на отдельные легкие для восприятия блоки - основная логика может состоять из пяти строчек

P.S. вы же знаете, что если файл лежит на той же машине, то его не через http надо считывать?

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Человек владеющие информацией - сильный человек.